# perl search and replace random text

Tags: perl, replace

```
foreach $suitename (@suitename)
    {
        foreach $fileLines (@fileLines)
        {
            if (index($fileLines, $suitename) != -1) 
            {
                    $str = $fileLines;
                    $find = "msg=\"/a-z/\"";
                    $replace = "msg=\"f\"";
                    $find = quotemeta $find;
                    $str =~ s/$find/$replace/g;
                    print $str; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Hi, I want to replace all $find, msg="random stuff" with $replace but I do not manage to do so. what i did was to get all my msg="random stuff" here @msg

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < scalar(@fileLines); $i++){
        if ($fileLines[$i] =~ /(msg=".*") /)
        {
         push (@msg,"$1\n");

        }
}
```

please advice.
thanks a lot

Comment: The first code snippet does not modify `@fileLines`. I think you're expecting it to do so. If you wish for that to happen you need to perform your substitution on `$fileLines`, not on `$str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta), you interpret `$find` literally. But removing it isn't enough, as the value you used isn't accurate: To match letters a-z, you can use a character class instead. To avoid backslashing double quotes, use single quotes:

```
$find    = 'msg="[a-z]"';
$replace = 'msg="f"';
```

If you want more than one character, add a `+` ("at least once"):

```
$find = 'msg="[a-z]+"';
```

Instead of a string, you can create a compiled regular expression with the `qr` operator:

```
$find = qr/msg="[a-z]+"/;
```